# How should I choose between a pegwall or slatwall as a tool storage solution?

Tags: walls, shelving, storage

I'm interested in putting up a tool wall in my garage/workshop.

Taking into consideration the price, strength, ease of use and versatility. Which of the two boards will be best for the job and what material (wood, metal, plastic...) would suite the enviroment?

**Links:** [Pegwall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforated_hardboard), [Slatwall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slatwall)

Comment: As for as what type of board to use, this is a personal preference and you are not going to get an "answer" on this but rather opinions.  I have both in my workshop and I use them for different things (bins on the slatboard, tools on the pegboard).  The other part of your question can only be answered with details on what you expect to hang.

Comment: why not a plywood wall with homemade brackets screwed/glued to it [like this guy](http://woodgears.ca/tool_holders/index.html)

Comment: @Steven: You're saying this won't get an answer but you've already started to answer the question by stating why you use one or the other. It may be your 'opinion' but it's helpful in the decision making process.

Comment: Perforated hardboard will have load issues but cost less and be more versatile for small items. Slatwall will likely cost more. What you use depends on what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just my preference/opinion on the subject.

Both types have their uses.  If you have space for more than a single board, I would advise a mixture with more peg boards then slat boards. If you only have space for a single board then I'd recommend a pegboard because I find them to be more versitile overall.

The slats are good for hanging bins while the pegboard can be used to hang just about anything on it, depending on the type of pegs you buy.

I have [these metal boards](http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/work-benches/cabinet/heavy-duty/18-x-19-pegboard-panel-blue-2).  They are rock solid feeling and I never have to worry about breaking them.  Relatively cheap too.  (I am not affiliated with this site, but have bought from them before).

[image: Metal board]

I also have some old wood boards in my basement from the previous owner of the house but a lot of the holes are broken.  I doubt I will ever need to replace the metal boards.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great DIY version of a wall-slat type system: [Hyper-Organize Your Shop](http://www.popularwoodworking.com/projects/hyperorganize-your-shop)

[image: wall slat shop setup]